# Pandas dataframe yields KeyError: -1

Tags: python, pandas

I got the error `KeyError: -1` on the following code:

```
u = []

for i in range(len(df['Some column'])):
   if df['Some column'][i] > df['Some column'][i-1]:
      u.append(df['Some column'][i])

print(u)
```

This is a pandas dataframe, where I try to print out the list of indexes [i] which are bigger than the previous index [i-1]. But it doesn't work, and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start the loop, `i` equals `0`, so `i-1` equals `-1`, which probably isn't in your index.

You could try

```
u = []

for i in range(1, len(df['Some column'])):
   if df['Some column'][i] > df['Some column'][i-1]:
      u.append(df['Some column'][i])

print(u)
```

Answer (score 1):

don't use loops you're losing the core functionality of pandas which is to take advantage of vectorised solutions.

we can use `shift` and `.tolist` to grab your desired result.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(50)

df = pd.DataFrame({'data' : np.random.randint(0,500,size=500)})

u = df.loc[df['data'] > df['data'].shift(-1)]['data'].tolist()

print(u)
out:
[480, 289, 478, 229, 278, 258, ...]
len(u)
out:
244
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason might lie in the fact that the index of your data frame may not be perfectly ordered from 0 to range(df). That is, your index may not necessarily be 1, 2, 3, 4,..., N. If your index is something like this:

```
1, 2, 30, 34, 45, 48, 50
```

Then, when you run the *for loop*, you will get this error. You might wanna try this first:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```